# comment to two participants, Simultaneously

Tags: support, comment-notification

How can one  send  comment to two  participants X  and  Y  simultaneously?

Does the  following  works

@X (and @Y).

I learned this  from  some  messages  by  moderatores  in meta. but I am not sure it works for all participants.

Thank you

Comment: What you wrote works *in chat* but not in comments (on main and meta). Some basic information on notification in comments is linked in [comment-notification tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/comment-notification/info). You can find there link to [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019), which also contains section "Can I notify more than one person at a time?" with more detailed information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, you can't. However, the author of the post will automatically receive inbox notification without the @name syntax. If user A is the author, and you want to reach user B as well (someone who has participated in the thread, via edit or comment), then by typing @B, both A and B will be notified. But if B has not participated in the post discussion, then B cannot be reached this way.

Most of the ins and outs of notification by comment, including which notifications are automatic without the @name mechanism, are explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). There is some extra clarification [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125208/when-exactly-do-i-get-comment-notifications).

Comment: @Martin  Dear  Todd and  Martin  I thank you so much for your kindly answer and  comment.

Comment: @AliTaghavi That doesn't work, because Martin did not participate on the comments for this answer, did not author the answer, did not edit the answer, and did not post the question.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo  Ah yes I see thanks.