# Only one addtional @user

Tags: discussion, comments, users, comment-notification

Why do we have this restriction?

---

[image: @notify]

---

There are many [circumstances](https://mathoverflow.net/a/359238/6094) where it is natural to
cite several users (especially when several=two) in one comment.

Comment: The system using at-sign is a potential source for spamming individuals with irrelevant messages.  To limit its abuse certain restrictions are in place, with the single user being one of them. Perhaps someone will provide a helpful link to documentation about this system.  Gerhard "This Is Where It's At" Paseman, 2020.05.03.

Comment: If it's important to cite two users, leave two comments.

Comment: Some related posts: [How do comment replies work? - section: Can I notify more than one person at a time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019), [Allow more than one @name notification per comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45273), [comment to two participants, Simultaneously](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3352). This was introduced probably at some point in 2011: [Should we discourage the use of multiple redundant `@username` pings in comments?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2094)

Comment: Just to clarify - your preference would be to have the situation before this change? (I.e., multiple @username is allowed, but only the first one creates the notification.) Or your preference would be to having possibility to ping several users by the same comment?

Comment: @MartinSleziak: The latter: ping several users in the same comment. But now I see the history behind the restriction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I be able to notify multiple people with the same comment?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/330/should-i-be-able-to-notify-multiple-people-with-the-same-comment)